# Has vs has had?

Tags: american-english, british-english

1.The bank crash **has had** a ripple effect on the whole community.

2.The Bank crash **has** a ripple effect  on the whole community.

Ok, so i came across the 1st sentence on an online dictionary and i wanna ask what's the difference between the 1st senyence and the 2nd sentence( i make this sentence myself). I know what present perfect is but why did the online dictionary use Has had and not has? Or are they both correct as well?  And can you explain the change in meaning on both of these sentences?

Based on my understanding, the 1st sentence means the activity  ( ripple effect)  is not long ago?

The second sentence is more oriented to a general sense? Like a normal occurence?

Comment: Hi, What research have you done about present perfect and present simple? Please edit your question to explain why you think that present simple might be OK. Which particular usage of present simple? https://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/english-grammar-reference/present-simple

Comment: @JavaLatte how about now?

Comment: If you are talking about a general truth, something that has happened before and will happen again, you can't be specific.. you have to say "**A** bank crash", not "**The** bank crash".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The difference is the usual difference between the present and the perfect tense. That is not about how long ago something happened.

The perfect tense talks about the current state, as result of a past action. That makes sense here: the banks crashed (some time in the past) but we are talking about the effect of that crash now

The second sentence is present tense.  Present tense has a range of uses, but is to talk about actions that happen now. In this sense it is similar in meaning to "The bank crash is having..."

> The coronavirus pandemic has ripple effects on the whole community.

Another sense is to speak of general facts. For this you could use a plural, so you could say:

> Bank crashes have a ripple effect...

These uses are rather less likely than "past event with present effects" so usually this would be in the form quoted in the  dictionary.

> The bank crash has had...